# AplicationData.Current

Tags: c#, sqlite

[image: Estoy tratando de crear la base de datos loca con sqlite tengo este codigo de la pagina de microsoft pero me sale un error en AplicationData no se que me falta agregar, pueden ayudarme por favor]
 No tengo idea si sea alguna clase que deba agregar o algo es primera vez con esto.

Comment: Por favor, no uses imágenes salvo que sea absolutamente necesario. Mira por favor [aca](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3976/324). Los errores y tu codigo deben ir como texto, siempre.

Comment: De casualidad no buscaste en google applicationdata.current no?

Comment: Que error te marca?

Comment: @RamiroBarone me dice que no existe en el contexto actual